# Adding custom blend behaviour on ListboxItem

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol, behavior

I am creating a custom blend behavior to act on a ListboxItem i.e.

```
public class DragtestBehaviour : Behavior<ListBoxItem>
{
    public DragtestBehaviour()
    { // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is attached to an object.
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is removed from an object.
    }
}
```

What I am not able to figure out is how do I attach it to the listboxitem?

Alternatively, do I have to style the Listbox item and attach it to Border or any other element in style? If this is true then do I have to also derive my behavior class from Border (i.e. Framework element)?

```
DragtestBehaviour : Behavior<Frameworkelement>
```

Comment: I would look into how you would attach a behavior in code and then design an attached property to serve as a proxy for your behavior ,
which would be placed on the listboxitems through  the listbox's ItemsContainerStyle

Comment: @eranotzap Yes it can be one way of doing it, but it also means the behavior is of no use in Blend. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: didn't notice that part of the question , good point .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have basically done what eran otzap suggested in his comment, and what is described in [this article](http://julmar.com/blog/programming/blend-behaviors-in-styles-dragpositionbehavior/) by Mark Smith. This allows to still use Blend Behaviors with its benefits (like `AssociatedObject`), but be more flexible about attaching it. It's a fusion of normal attached behavior with blend behavior.

For completeness sake, here's the relevant code as well.

Attach the behavior in `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="behaviors:DragDropBehavior.IsAttached" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Behavior

```
public class DragDropBehavior : Behavior<ListBoxItem>
{
    // IsAttached
    public static DependencyProperty IsAttachedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsAttached",typeof(bool), typeof(DragDropBehavior),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsAttachedChanged));
    public static bool GetIsAttached(DependencyObject o){return (bool)o.GetValue(IsAttachedProperty);}
    public static void SetIsAttached(DependencyObject o, bool value){o.SetValue(IsAttachedProperty, value);}

    // is called the same as when attached in Interaction.Behaviors tag
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {            
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    // manual attachement to listbox item
    private static void OnIsAttachedChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var el = o as UIElement;
        if (el != null)
        {
            var behColl = Interaction.GetBehaviors(el);
            var existingBehavior = behColl.FirstOrDefault(b => b.GetType() == typeof(DragDropBehavior)) as DragDropBehavior;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == false && existingBehavior != null)
            {
                behColl.Remove(existingBehavior);
            }
            else if ((bool)e.NewValue == true && existingBehavior == null)
            {
                behColl.Add(new DragDropBehavior());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ adabyron Thanks for posting the code. Think this is a good way to go ahead